# why application detect an image as nil in swift 3?

Tags: ios, json, swift3, uiimage, avatar

when my app wants to download avatar(profile image) it will crash and show me the Error but my image is not nil But the application detect that its nil here is the Error massage

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

and here is the print of my image Data and image that proves the image is not nil

, {0, 0}
10059 bytes

and here is my codes for downloading Avatar(profile Image)

```
let avatarUrl = URL(string: "http://example.com/uploads/avatar/\(EmailSignInViewController.avatar)")!
 let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)

// Define a download task. The download task will download the contents of the URL as a Data object and then you can do what you wish with that data.

let downloadPicTask = session.dataTask(with: avatarUrl) { (data, response, error) in

        // The download has finished.

                if let e = error {
            print("Error downloading cat picture: \(e)")
                                 } else {

                              // No errors found.
// It would be weird if we didn't have a response, so check for that too.

if let res = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
   print("Downloaded personal picture with response code \(res.statusCode)")
           if let imageData = data {

 // Finally convert that Data into an image and do what you wish with it.

      print(imageData)
      print(profileViewController.userImage)                                                                                

if #available(iOS 10, *) {

profileViewController.userImage = UIImage(data: imageData )!

} else {


 profileViewController.userImage = UIImage(named: "user.jpg")!

 }


 // Do something with your image.


 } else {

 print("Couldn't get image: Image is nil")

 }

  } 
 else {

 print("Couldn't get response code for some reason")
                                                                              }



  }



   }


   downloadPicTask.resume()
```

Comment: Which line exactly is causing the error?

Comment: po of the image data being 10059 bytes means there is a data but is that data is of image or is it possible to convert it to image or not is not confirmed, What I am thinking is  UIImage(data: imageData )! returns nil

Comment: Then clearly the data is not actually image data or it's not a supported image type.

Comment: Why is that only if its iOS10 then u use image data that u downloaded else u load a local image from bundle "user.jpg" is that image present ???

Comment: the strange thing is that until yesterday noon this was working as soon as the man who editing web services this problem happened But he said I didn't change any thing is that possible?

Comment: @saeed-rahmatolahi : Possible if he modified the resource being sent on url and made it to send something else other than image

Comment: so you mean the problem is not in my codes? and he should change web services codes?

Comment: @saeed-rahmatolahi : I can see the image is a plain get request why don't u put the url in web browser and hit if it loads image then no problem in his code else its his code that need to be modified

Comment: Check if the outlet for userImage is connected in profileViewController

Comment: I told you this was working well and suddenly it doesn't work I didn't change the codes I think the problem is in webservices